# how to read external json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
[
  ["timestamp","bfx_l","bfx_h","bfx_bv","bfx_b_s","bfx_b_l","bfx_s_s","bfx_s_s","okc_bv"  ],
  ["0","225.25","225.25","225.63248","","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["1","225.25","225.25","225.63248","","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["2","225.25","225.25","225.63527","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["3","225.25","225.25","225.62688","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["4","225.25","225.25","225.62688","","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["5","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["6","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["7","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["8","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["9","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["10","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["11","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["12","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["13","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["14","225.25","225.25","225.64536","224.57","","","","224.32"  ]
]
```

This is my `dataset.json` external json file. First row is header and all other rows are data .

```
$.getJSON('dataset.json', function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
```

This is a function of jquery. But I could not get the data using this function. I need to separate the header and then data line by line. How to do it?

Thanks in advance

**Update**

I don't need to use variable and then put it in same file. I need to call json from external json file as above and than put that data in highstock chart. So I need a solution for reading external json file.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, test it here: [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @Mottie JSON  is valid!

Comment: Nope, there is an extra comma at the end of line 14...

Comment: its a valid json i check it on jsonlint

Comment: it's valid JS, it's not valid JSON

Comment: you can ajax the url and eval(theResponse) to get an array

Answer (score 1):

After you fix the error on line 17 (remove the superfluous `,` after the closing square bracket), you have to process the multi-dimensional array in the same way that you would process CSV in PHP.

A more effective method of storing JSON (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is to utilise the benefits that it gives you and actually store your content in object notation. Instead of having an array like:

```
["13","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ]
```

You should have arrays like:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp":"13",
        "bfx_l":"225.25",
        "bfx_h":"225.25",
        "bfx_bv":"225.62943",
        "bfx_b_s":"225.03",
        "bfx_b_l":"",
        "bfx_s_s":"",
        "bfx_s_s":"",
        "okc_bv":"224.32"
    }
]
```

You can run that through JSONLint as well and it will validate.

Then all you need to do is a for loop over each object in the array and directly refer to the object keys, rather than extract the keys from the first header row and then map the values for each subsequent row to the header keys (eg. CSV style).

Answer (score 0):

A method I have used in the past is to use a call back function. I'm not suggesting this is the definitive solution but simply a solution.

The strategy I have used is to:

- append the data file to the SCRIPT tag and then
- invoke a call back function

In that call back function you can then access the data. This can be done by looping through each record.

The code below will do that:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function getData() {
            var src_file = 'dataset.json';
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.src = src_file;
            var el = (document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]);
            el.appendChild(script);

            window.data_callback = function(results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                    alert(results[i]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='getData()'>
</body>
</html>
```

I nearly forgot to mention that in the data file you need to wrap your data arrays in `data_callback([...]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(json) {
                        val1 = [];
                        val2 = [];
                        val3 = [];
                        val4 = [];
                            $.each(json, function(key,value) {
                                 val1.push([Number(value[0]), Number(value[1])]);
                                 val2.push([Number(value[0]), Number(value[2])]);
                                 val3.push([Number(value[0]), Number(value[3])]);
                                 val4.push([Number(value[0]), Number(value[8])]);
                            });
                             var newvalue = [];
                             if(i == 0){
                                 newvalue = val1;
                             }
                             else if(i == 1){
                                 newvalue = val2;
                             }
                             else if(i == 2){
                                 newvalue = val3;
                             }
                             else if(i == 3){
                                 newvalue = val4;
                             }
                             seriesOptions[i] = {
                                 name: name,
                                 data: newvalue
                             };
                             seriesCounter += 1;

                             if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                                 createChart();
                             }
                     });
```

this is working for me

Answer (score -1):

You can map the data to array of objects using the following:

```
var columns = data.shift();
var results = data.map(function(row){   
   return row.reduce(function(rowObj, elem, i){
       rowObj[columns[i]] = elem;
       return rowObj;
   },{});
});
```

```js
var data =[
  ["timestamp","bfx_l","bfx_h","bfx_bv","bfx_b_s","bfx_b_l","bfx_s_s","bfx_s_s","okc_bv"  ],
  ["0","225.25","225.25","225.63248","","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["1","225.25","225.25","225.63248","","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["2","225.25","225.25","225.63527","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["3","225.25","225.25","225.62688","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["4","225.25","225.25","225.62688","","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["5","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["6","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["7","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["8","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["9","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["10","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["11","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["12","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["13","225.25","225.25","225.62943","225.03","","","","224.32"  ],
  ["14","225.25","225.25","225.64536","224.57","","","","224.32"  ],
]

var columns = data.shift();

var results = data.map(function(row){   
   return row.reduce(function(rowObj, elem, i){
       rowObj[columns[i]] = elem;
       return rowObj;
   },{});
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(results, null, 4) +'</pre>';
```